# Why has this correct answer been deleted?

Tags: discussion, deletion

This identification question [Song playing in Lift Me Up first dance scene](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/4891/song-playing-in-lift-me-up-first-dance-scene) has received a correct answer and a link to the singer's website with the song. Even the asker confirmed it was the right answer in a comment.

However, the answer was deleted with no specified reason. Is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was pretty much a link only answer that just seemed to go to an irrelevant site and looked more like spam than anything else (the video doesn't even show up in my browser). This is a huge problem with these questions as they generate a lot of flags due to the nature of the answers which are links with minimal text. I can undelete it if it makes sense, but that only treats the symptoms not the issue at hand.

We currently have a lot of flags like this pending on similar answers that's really hard to judge one way or another due to us not having a set format for those question and answers.

Comment: As long as we accept identification questions, we have to admit that sometimes, the correct answer is a one-line answer (the name and the title) with the link, and there is not much to add at the answer.

Comment: I edited the answer so it doesn't look look a spam anymore.